# Is it possible to have a camera track a new empty in the middle of an animation?

Tags: animation, camera

I don't think it's possible, but I'd like to have one camera filming a single scene instead of binding different cameras to markers.

Is it possible to have a camera track an empty and then part way through an animation, move to a new empty and track that?

Answer (score 6):

You can have several *"track to"* constraints, and animate (keyframe) their respective influences:

[image]